# Cannot assign to read only property of Object in TypeScript

Tags: reactjs, typescript

Can anyone please explain to me why and how this might happen?

I have a typescript app with Zustand state management.

Somewhere inside the app I am updating certain elements by extracting them from the state and cloning them via a simple `Object.Assign` :

```
let elemToUpdate = Object.assign({},story?.content?.elementsData[nodeId]);

if (elemToUpdate) {

    if (elemToUpdate.title) elemToUpdate.title[editorLang] = newName;

    else elemToUpdate.title = {[editorLang]:newName} as TextDictionary;

    updateElement(nodeId,elemToUpdate);
}
```

Now the interesting part is: on my first try the update goes through without fail, but the next object I am trying to update fails with the following message:

`Tree.tsx:39 Uncaught TypeError: Cannot assign to read only property 'en' of object '#<Object>'`

I can't understand WHY the first one comes through, but the second gets blocked.

I know HOW to fix this: I need to do a deep clone. I just want to understand WHY.

Answer (score 4):

*First*, let's start from why some objects in your code are `readonly`. Based on what you described in the question, you use a Zustand state manager. Such managers traditionally wraps your stored data to readonly objects to prevent their manual mutation (expecting that you will change the state only via built-in mechanisms) to guarantee data stability. So, if the `story?.content?.elementsData[nodeId]` is the Zustand state object, it and all its nested objects are converted to readonly.

*Second*, let's define, which objects will be blocked. I see at least two objects here: `elemToUpdate: { ..., title: { [lang]: string }}` (that is `elemToUpdate` and its `title`). Both will be converted to readonly.

*Third*, you use `Object.assign({}, ...)` which creates a new object (new reference) and clones all the properties of the source object. Please note that this happens only for the first level of properties, it's not a deep clone. So, as the `title` is a reference to another object, it will be cloned as-is and in the new object it will still lead to the existing `{ [lang]: string }` object. There are several ways to solve that:

1. deep clone, as you mentioned
2. manually clone `title` property, for instance `{..., title: { ... elemToUpdate.title }}` or via Object.assign

But I would not suggest you to mutate objects this way. Most probably your entire algorithm has some architectural issues in general.

Answer (score 2):

That is expected because in the first case you are not assigning a new value to the `title` property: you are only changing a value *inside* the `title` property. In the second case you are reassigning the whole value of the `title` property.

You can't change a `readonly` property. Let's understand it with a simple example:

**Javascript:** Only for example not related to problem

```
const user = { // a const is immutable
    name: 'John',
}
user.name = 'Pete'; // This works


const user = {
    name: 'John'
}
user = { name: 'Pete'} // This doesn't work
```

**Typescript:**

```
const user: Readonly<{
   a: {
        name: string
   }
}> = {
  a:{ name: 'John' }
}

user.a.name = 'Pete'; // This works
user.a = { name: 'John' } // Does not work
```

The same is happening in your example: Typescript does not check deep Readonly props. Please check [here](https://www.typescriptlang.org/play?#code/MYewdgzgLgBArhApgJwFwwEqIIYBNwA2AngDwDeAUDNdupdQw2NgLaLrTICWYA5ldQC%20FQQD4YAXhj0YtMtWZt0AcgBSIABZhlAGmHCKCFADpsxxYkkwARAAVEURNYDcMAPRuYAFQ1cIMAHcQZABrCEMkZFNzVkspeRgLFXUtXUF3TzAQWCDQoA)